# unable to pod install in Xcode. ( cocoa pods )

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am working on a project which requires firebase and few other cocoa pods, I am able to install firebase but unable to install few other pods. every time I'm trying to install pods it throws the error below, there was no problem two days back..

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod install
```

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.9.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3
        Host : Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
       Xcode :  ()
         Git : git version 2.19.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : master - git - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 241fe3335bd01f8cc484053cf0a694498679863a

               trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.4
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.1.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.5.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Blab' do
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Blab

# Firebase
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'

# Pods
pod 'MessageKit'
pod 'JGProgressHUD'
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'SDWebImage'

end
```

#### Error

```
JSON::ParserError - 416: unexpected token at '"S'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/json/common.rb:156:in `parse'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification/json.rb:61:in `from_json'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:742:in `from_string'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:716:in `from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:186:in `specification'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver/lazy_specification.rb:37:in `specification'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb:348:in `block in delegating_block'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/delegate.rb:349:in `block in delegating_block'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:178:in `dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:18:in `block in dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:70:in `with_no_such_dependency_error_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/delegates/specification_provider.rb:17:in `dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:807:in `block in group_possibilities'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:806:in `reverse_each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:806:in `group_possibilities'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:778:in `possibilities_for_requirement'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:761:in `push_state_for_requirements'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:746:in `require_nested_dependencies_for'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:729:in `activate_new_spec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:686:in `attempt_to_activate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1065:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1063:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:235:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.9.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

---

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `13.0` on target `Blab` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

I tried to uncomment the below line..

## platform :ios, '9.0'

but unable to figure out what the problem is!
if anyone could tell me what the problem is that would be great.

Comment: With some pods you should have the latest version of xCode and I also recommend the latest one from macOS. I don't know if this is also the case with firebase. Have you tried installing [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/) from scratch? 
Also try generating a new Podfile with `pod init`.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569 ? I would focus on that error first.

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/
#Uncomment the platform part in Podfile
pod repo update --verbos
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess its working fine

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```